# Get status of react query mutation

Tags: react-query

While using react query mutation i have faced the issue that im not getting the updated value of isSuccess / isError from the mutation.
What can cause isSuccess being always set to false?

**Usage**

```
const { mutate: updatePropertyMapping } = useMutationPropertyMapping();
```

**Mutation implementation**

```
const useMutationPropertyMapping = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation<
    Integration, // Replace with your Integration type
    AxiosError,
    {
      integrationType: keyof typeof IntegrationTypesCRM;
      newPropertyMapping: MappedProperty[];
      groupId?: string;
    }
  >(
    ({ integrationType, newPropertyMapping, groupId }) => {
      return IntegrationtService.UpdateIntegrationPropertyMapping({
        integrationType,
        newPropertyMapping,
        groupId,
      });
    },
    {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      onSuccess: (updatedGroupIntegration, variables) => {
        const queryKey = ['integration', variables.integrationType, 'propertyMapping', variables.groupId || 'default'];
        queryClient.refetchQueries(queryKey);

        if ((updatedGroupIntegration as any)?.error) {
          toast.error('Something went wrong');
        }
        // toast.success('Mapping Updated Success');
      },
      onError: ({ response }) => {
        const hubspotErrorMessage = response?.data?.message;
        const errMessage = 'Something went wrong';
        toast.error(errMessage);
      },
    },
  );
};
```

**The service function**

```
UpdateIntegrationPropertyMapping: async ({
    integrationType,
    newPropertyMapping,
    groupId,
  }: {
    integrationType: keyof typeof IntegrationTypesCRM;
    newPropertyMapping: MappedProperty[];
    groupId?: string;
  }) => {
    const response = await fetch({
      url: `/integration/propertyMapping`,
      method: 'put',
      data: {
        integrationType,
        newPropertyMapping,
        groupId,
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  },
```